# How does PWM work on an Xbee Wi-Fi Module S6B?

Tags: pwm, xbee

I've read that the PWM on an Xbee is 15625 Hz and that it is somehow different from the PWM used to run motors. What is the difference?

> Note: The XBee PWM is not the same type of PWM used for servos. This is a PWM-controlled voltage level as opposed to a PWM signal."

per [*Getting Started with XBee RF Modules*](http://forums.parallax.com/discussion/140192/if-xbee-pwm-isn-t-the-kind-of-pwm-servos-can-use-then-what-kind-of-pwm-is-it).

This image shows some examples of PWM outputs over time:
[image]

If a picture is the best explanation, please post one of the output of an Xbee PWM signal over time.

Comment: How is that different? 15625 Hz is a frequency. While 50% (or whatever) is duty cycle.

Comment: http://forums.parallax.com/discussion/140192/if-xbee-pwm-isn-t-the-kind-of-pwm-servos-can-use-then-what-kind-of-pwm-is-it and

Comment: I WANT to get an adequate enough square wave out of an Xbee to run a piezo. I don't know if the differences make that more possible because I've read comments that the frequency is modulated somehow.

Answer (score 1):

PWM is PWM, technique for controlling analog circuits with a processor's digital outputs. Important things in PWM are that you need to know base frequency of your core or modified frequency after using PLLs/frequency multipliers, then resolution and duty cycle you need.

[image]

In your case if PWM frequency is 15.625 KHz and you have resolution of 4, then you get base/modified frequency which is 4*15.625 = 62.5 KHz

All of this parameters I wrote above depend on your application and are adapted to it.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of what differs with the Xbee modules.